# Disable version column in Grails affect performance?

Tags: grails

I just disabled the **version** column on one of my domain objects. It's accessed by many threads and was causing lots of stale state errors. The method which uses this object the most seems to be going slower all of a sudden. I haven't done any tests to verify this, but I just wanted to throw it out there and see if performance can be affected by disabling the version column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely that disabling it would affect performance; if anything, it should make things very slightly faster (but not enough that it should ever be a reason to do nor not make this change).

But disabling the feature because of stale state errors is probably not the right way to go. Concurrent updates will result in lost data if you don't use explicit locking (which can be very non-performant), so you're just trading an apparent fix for less obvious but more serious bugs.

Comment: Thanks Burt -- This Concurrent Mod stuff has been an absolute nightmare. I've received mixed answers regarding the best way to fix it and ultimately just got frustrated with it.

Comment: Is any proper solution except disable version in table for optimistic locking.?

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good blog [post](http://mybreadbasket.blogspot.com.br/2009/11/optimistic-concurrency-control-by.html) explaining in details how pessimistic/optimistic locking works and why removing optimistic locking doesn't affect the performance of your app. But also it doesn't make performance significantly worse or causes deadlock. It usually is the way to go.